# Corruption of in-memory data detected: where does the issue lie?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7, vps, xfs, corruption

We are experiencing crashes on our SSD VPSes, all working on KVM: crashes occur for different reasons; in the hurry to restore the service my team uses to reload a previous snapshot of the machine and never saves the logs.

Anyway, among all the different crashes circumstances, a recurring fact is the `corruption of in-memory data`: our VPS provider told us their hardware is running fine, yet I don't know how to read the poor log I was given.

[image]

**What is involved when an "in-memory data corruption" is detected?** Could it be because of broken RAM, or there are other kinds of memory corruption?

Funny thing: a VPS provider using VMware never gave us troubles, the one using KVM is really driving us crazy because of these crashes.

**Edit 1**: I, by no means, demand that you people deduce the solution from this miserable log. I'm stuck with this issue where no decent log is provided, `memtest` is useless since the hardware is emulated and the VPS provider granted that their hardware is fine and no instances of KVM or QEMU crashed. `corruption of in-memory data detected` is haunting me, and I can't think of any productive approach to investigate further this issue.

Comment: Do you know what is the host OS and configuration the hoster provides? I have seen such issues with a large cloud provider who was using ubuntu 14 for their hosts, and were running KSM non-stop in a loop (because they had no idea how to do it properly).

Comment: The provider keeps its KVM configurations secret so I don't know what arguments they use with KVM, nor the underlying OS.

Comment: See if you can reproduce this on another provider

Answer (score 5):

["Corruption of in-memory data detected"](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/93483) doesn't necessarily mean that the hardware RAM is bad. It could also indicate a block was read or written incorrectly, the storage flipped a bit or is otherwise failing, possibly filesystem bugs, and a few other causes.

Reverting to a snapshot probably won't resolve the problem if there is some latent filesystem corruption; it'll just show up again later.

Instead, you should `xfs_repair` the filesystem, but since it's the root filesystem you'll need to [boot from installation media](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2018903) or a rescue environment provided by your VPS provider.

If `xfs_repair` fails to repair the filesystem, you may run `xfs_repair -L` which will clear the XFS log (which may itself be corrupt) and then try to repair the filesystem again.

Comment: Knowledgebase of RedHat is unavailable to me since I'm not a customer, but at least you gave a direction. Thanks a lot

Comment: @elmazzun I missed your comment for some reason. If you sign up for the [free Red Hat subscription](https://developers.redhat.com/) you will also get access to their knowledge base.

Comment: Just ran into this on VMWare ESXi, didn't expect to be able to run a command like this from the emergency shell.. but gosh darn it actually worked.. and it worked well.